# How do I ask for larger images in react native (react-native-fbsdk) when asking for more then just invitable_friends data?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, react-native

Im trying to get larger images for the users returned with invitable_friends. If I split it up in several calls it works just fine, but as soon as I ask for all the data in one request I can't figure out how to specify the image size.
Any suggestions?

My current request:

```
new GraphRequest('/me',
   {parameters: {
      'fields': {
           'string' : 'gender, name, friends, invitable_friends, picture.width(300)'
         }
   }},
   ((error, result) => {                                                                            
   }),
);
```

The request that is working for fetching only invitable_friends with larger images:

```
new GraphRequest('/me/invitable_friends',
   {parameters: {
      'fields': {
           'string' : 'name,picture.width(300)'
         }
   }},
   ((error, result) => {                                                                            
   }),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Field Expansion syntax, you can write this as

```
invitable_friends{name,picture.width(300)}
```

in the field list.